# Installing Torque on a single machine

Tags: torque

Does anyone know if I can install Torque on a multicore machine instead of across a cluster?  We're looking to test some software that requires Torque and exceeds the hardware capability of our LSF based cluster.

We have a multicore machine that actually could meet the demands, except that the software is set up to require the use of Torque over a cluster - one thought I had was setting up this machine to look like a torque cluster to the software and perhaps that would work.

Comment: How about setting up a few VM's (one for each core) and have them in a cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done. There are some [great instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1372508) in the Ubuntu forum for setting up a standalone Torque server.